# Use valgrind xml-file and log-file option together

Tags: xml, logging, valgrind

Has anyone tried to use valgrind such that both the text log as well as the xml output are created?

I have tried: 
1. To use these options together: `--xml=yes --xml-file=log.xml --log-file=log.txt`
   [ This only created the xml file. log.txt was empty] 
2. All sorts of redirections ( `&>, 2>&1, & tee`) to create the log.txt since creating the xml is happening with the above mentioned xml flags 
   [ Only the std output messages from my program came on to log.txt ]

Any other way to do this?

Comment: Encounter the same problem, did you solve it?

Comment: Nope, stil don't get both (log & xml) in one run

Answer (score 0):

No need of using tool option to set it to 'memcheck', since by default valgrind uses 'memcheck' as the tool. Just for your information. Even there is no issue also, in using tool option.

Try using the below command, to get the logs in both XML file and log file.

```
valgrind --xml=yes --xml-file=XMLFile.log > Textlog.log 2>&1 test
```

Is this one you are expecting?

more information can be found in below link,

http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.basicopts

Answer (score 0):

From the core manual for valgrind.

> When enabled, the important parts of the output (e.g. tool error messages) will be in XML format rather than plain text.

I turned on verbose, --verbose, to get less important stuff to be printed and I now have my log and xml files populated while turned on at the same time.